# Removing top,bottom extra space without height changing?

Tags: echarts, apache-echarts

Hello everyone is it possible to remove top and bottom white space without changing my chart height?

```js
grid: {
   bottom: 0,
   top: 0,
}
```

The above is not a good option. Destroys my graph because height is auto I belive.
[image]

[image]

New screenshot with top and bottom at 30,
[image]

Comment: top and bottom specify the distance in pixels from the coordinate grid of the chart. If set to 0 everything above/beneath the grid itself will be cut off. Try a few other values to get your expected result.

Comment: Still if i go 30,30 for example my chart will resize the height. Maybe I should give specific height

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve. Why is it a problem if the chart height is different?

Comment: What I want is to put my Ideal, Not Ideal more close to my graph without changing my graph height. I will post a screenshot to my main question in a minute to understand what I mean exactly

Comment: Ah... So this depends on how you realized the label. If it is a visual map you can set top / bottom of the visual map

Comment: I will check visual map. My label is external not related with the chart just an other stack below.

Comment: If you would share the code it would be easier to help. Maybe you can make an example in the [echarts online editor](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=line-simple).